# Issue with Assignment Operator and Array Subscription operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload subscription operator and faced with some issue
for example my class is **E**, what I did at first is:

```
int E::operator[](int n){
    if(n<length && n>0)
        return data[n];
    else
        return 0;

}
```

let say I have an object of **E** ( A ), and I want to return the A[0]. this operator works fine.
the second thing I wanted to do is if I want to do `A[0] = 4`. 
what I need to implement here? assignment operator? or subscription operator?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you clarify?

Comment: Also, `if(n<=length)` will lead to failure if n < 0 or n = length.

Comment: what I added here is working, its return the `data[n]`, what I want to do in addition to what I did is to make assignment to an object of class E so `E[0]= value`, so my question is what I need to do for implement it?

Comment: Note that in standard library containers, `operator[](size_t n)` tends to be unchecked, and member function `at(size_t)` provided range-checked element access, in case you want your class to have behaviour consistent with that of the std library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonly the subscript operator is written with two overloads: One to read and one to write. This allows you to read in const contexts:

### Write overload:

```
int& E::operator[](size_t index)
{
    if( index >= lenght )
        throw std::out_of_range("Subscript out of range");
    else
        return data[n];
}
```

### Read overload: (Note that is const cualified)

```
int E::operator[](size_t index) const
{
    if( index >= lenght )
        throw std::out_of_range("Subscript out of range");
    else
        return data[n];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return reference to element, i.e.

```
int& E::operator[](size_t n)
{
   if ( n >= length)
      throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
   return data[n];
}
```

Comment: What about when n = length?